# I cannot access properly a list of dictionaries from a JSON response using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a json response decode with utf and access the dictionaries in the list. The following is the JSON response

```
'[{"id":26769687,"final_price":58.9,"payment_method_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 0,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΑντικαταβολή\\u003c/span\\u003e","net_price":53.9,"net_price_formatted":"53,90 €","final_price_formatted":"58,90 €","shop_id":649,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-5.0,-156,-201,649,20],"payment_method_cost_supported":true,"free_shipping_cost_supported":false,"shipping_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 5,00 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΜεταφορικά\\u003c/span\\u003e","link":"/products/show/26769687"}, 
{"id":26771682,"final_price":55.17,"payment_method_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 2,83 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΑντικαταβολή\\u003c/span\\u003e","net_price":48.5,"net_price_formatted":"48,50 €","final_price_formatted":"55,17 €","shop_id":54,"no_credit_card":false,"sorting_score":[-3.6,-169,-84,54,10],"payment_method_cost_supported":true,"free_shipping_cost_supported":false,"shipping_cost":"\\u003cem\\u003e+ 3,84 €\\u003c/em\\u003e \\u003cspan\\u003eΜεταφορικά\\u003c/span\\u003e","link":"/products/show/26771682"}]'
```

which is produce by the following

```
url2besearched = 'https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/20783507/product_prices.js?_=1569161647'    
Delays = [25,18,24,26,20,22,19,30]    
no_of_pagedowns= 20
RandomDelays = np.random.choice(Delays) 

#WAIT TIME    
time.sleep(RandomDelays)

fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url2besearched)
mybytes = fp.read()
post_elems =[]
mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
mystr1 = mystr.rsplit('=')
mystr2 = mystr1[1].split(";")
#I ADD THE FOLLOWING BECAUSE THE INITIAL DOES NOT HAVE ENDING BRACKETS
mystr3 = mystr2[0]+"}"+"]"

for d in mystr3:
    for key in d:
        post_elems.append([d[key],d['final_price'],d['shop_id']])
```

When I do the for loop is getting character by character the mystr3 variable and not as a dictionary 
How can I have a list with the key of dictionary and final_price with shop_id

My desired output needs to be a list like

```
post_elems =['26769687','58.9','649']
```

Comment: Option one: `import json`, `json.loads(reply)`
Option two: `import requests` directly, `requests.get(...).json()`

Comment: I do it and I get msg about error in decoding. In which place should I put the loads(reply) ?

Comment: Your string has escaped characters, such as \\u003c (lesser than?). It is likely that. The greek (Metaforica etc) is unicode, but should be fine with JSON (unless you are using the ancient python 2)

Comment: Also note that JS truth values and null are converted to strings. So you will get 'false':str as a value.

Comment: Its Python 3.7 I place json.loads(mystr) but I get JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: This line `mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")` seems to be the problem: python 2, not needed in 3.

Comment: But as mentioned, unless your JSON is huge and needs to be sent in chunks, use https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: Can you present me please a whole solution? thank you

Answer (score 0):

First the API you are calling for some reason gives a weird response. So `.json()` on response will not work as there is a field in front. It would be good to understand why or check the URL query strings are correct. Anyway. You have removed them. So I'll copy that code:

```
import requests, json
mystr = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/20783507/product_prices.js?_=1569161647').text
mystr1 = mystr.rsplit('=')
mystr2 = mystr1[1].split(";")[0]
json.loads(mystr2)
```

This works. However. there are two things that are not great here. `mystr1` is a systems Hugarian notation, this is very unpythonic. Use type-hinting to help remind what class something belongs to, not the variable name. Also your mystr2 gives a list, a nice example why Hugarian notation is bad.

Comment: How to get the post_elems =['26769687','58.9','649'] then?

Comment: There are many ways of getting these from a list of dictionaries. Ranging from [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to [Pandas dataframe.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and getting the column.

Comment: I don't recall what your data looked like, but it would be something like `post_elems =[record['post_elems'] for record in records]`.